# Laravel DB Query Not Working in server but in local host is running well

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

DB Query was running well but i think there is a content of a file changed during uploading files to update

I use simple query to get Data from data base but didn't work

it Not running after DB query

```
$symptoms = DB::table('symptoms')->select('MainSymptoms','Symptom')->get();
return json_encode($symptoms);
```

Comment: what's the error you getting ?

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: thats none debug error. open storage/logs/laravel.log see what's the error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

probably your database config is wrong.

first you need to see the error so go to config/App.php and change "debug" to true like that:

```
'debug' => 'true'
```

and then you will be able to see where is the problem and you can solve it

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: the error is (Connection refusedSQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused)